# How to change the type of menu on a jquery click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I currently have a menu as follows:

```
<select name="select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange+'" id="select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange+'" data-native-menu="false">\
                    <option>Choose fields</option>\
                    <option value="A">A</option>\
                    <option value="B">B</option>\
</select>
```

On a click, event, I want it to change to:

```
<select name="select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange+'" id="select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange+'" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">\
                    <option>Choose fields</option>\
                    <option value="A">A</option>\
                    <option value="B">B</option>\
</select>
```

Notice I added a "multiple" to the select statement.

I'm trying to do this when the #flip-min toggle button is called. I can get an alert to trigger when the toggle is hit, I just need to be able to change the select statement. How does one do that?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried? $('#select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange+').attr('multiple','multiple'); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can do it like..

```
$('#flip-min').click(function(){
 $('select#YourSelectElementID').attr('multiple','multiple');
});
```

To remove the multiple attribute, just use,

```
$('select#YourSelectElementID').removeAttr('multiple');
```

you will need to check the status of the toggle button and call the statements conditionally.

But I am not sure if the ID you provided for the SELECT element (select-choice-'+symbol+'-'+exchange+') is a valid one or not. Why don't you use a better ID?

Comment: Assume the OP want's to remove the attr instead of add it

Comment: why is it: $('select#YourSelectElementID') and not just $('#YourSelectElementID')

Comment: You can use that too. Your suggestion is shorter. But this became my habit to write it like this so that I can identify the element type when looking at the script itself. Sorry for that :)